# joining scalar valued function to a table taking that column generated by SVF as in input

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i have scalar valued function which is called and it gives a new column values  in the table, now I want to join this new column value  to a column of new table which I have added as derived table in sql server 2005.

Comment: Can you provide more details? A code sample, even a non-working one, of what you've tried so far would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use that function in a `JOIN`, something like this:

```
SELECT {fieldlist}
FROM {tablename} a
    JOIN {tablename} b ON b.{fieldname} = dbo.{functionname}({parameters})
```

But, as Joe stated, a code sample would make this a bit less theoretical and more useful for the rest of the community.